# SVerilog can't compile in VSCode

Tags: system-verilog, iverilog

Here are the cods (1st one is the testbench and the second one the module)

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps 
`include "not_example1.sv" 

module testbench;
    parameter BITS = 4;
    logic [BITS-1:0] s_in;
    logic [BITS-1:0] s_model_outs; 

not_example1     #(.NUM(BITS))   not_model    (.i_a(s_in), .o_y1(s_model_outs));
    
initial
    begin 
            $dumpfile("signals.vcd");  
                                        
            $dumpvars(0,testbench);     

        s_in = '0;
        #1  
            s_in = '1;
        #1  s_in = '0;
        #1  s_in = '1;
        
        #1 

            $finish;
        
        end
endmodule
```

Module

```
module not_example1 (i_a, o_y1);

    parameter NUM = 4;
    input  logic [NUM-1:0] i_a;
output logic [NUM-1:0] o_y1;

always_comb
begin
    o_y1 = ~ i_a;
end

endmodule
```

Basically the error is that I can't compile the testbench program. I'm writting everything in SystemVerilog (.sv). The message I get is :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dleAW.png)

I don't know what is this -g2005-sv. Is it something I should download ? Because the code to compile .sv file is correct I guess.

Comment: what is vsc? how did you compile? which errors did you see? Do not insert links to code, insert the code itself. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Serge Edited, I belive now it's better :)

Comment: Your code is a syntactically correct 'system verilog' code.  -g2005 runs iverilog in a simple verilog mode. So, it will not be compatible with your program. To run in system verilog mode you need -g2012. But even in this case icarus does not support the full extend of system verilog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a syntactically correct 'system verilog' code.  However, iverilog is not a good tool to compile it.

`-g2005` runs iverilog in a verilog `2K` mode. It does not understand any of SV constructs. So, it will not be compatible with your program. To run in system verilog mode you need `-g2012`. But even in this case, icarus does not support a lot of system verilog constructs. In your case it had trouble with the not_example1 module. I tried to modify it to make compatible with iverilog (10.0) -g2012 in eda-playground.

```
module not_example1 (i_a, o_y1);
  parameter NUM = 4;
  input  [NUM-1:0] i_a; // logic did not work here
  output reg [NUM-1:0] o_y1; // logic did not work here

always @* // always_comb did not work
begin
    o_y1 = ~ i_a;
end

endmodule
```

EDA playground only has version 10 installed. So, you can try 11 on your own it might be more tolerant to your original constructs.

Comment: I've compiled it with the original code using -g2005 and I guess it worked ? Because in the gtkwave it showed everything alight except one thing which was parameter. Because on gtkwave it showed that the NUM[31:0] which I don't underestand I can edit the post but I don't know if it will be helpfull Also I use 12.0 iverilog